# Printing vector of sets in c++

Tags: c++, vector, set

Is there anyway to print a vector of sets easily?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  std::vector<std::set<int> > setVector;
  int myints[] = {5,10,15};
  int elementCount = sizeof(myints) / sizeof(myints[0]);
  myset.insert(myints, myints + elementCount);
  setVector.push_back(myset);
  std::cout << "Elements in vector: " << setVector.size() << " \n";
}
```

I have added the set to the vector, is there anyway to print it out?

This is just a proof of concept, eventually I will add many more sets to this vector, so ideally I will need to print from the beginning of the vector to the end

Thank you

Comment: You have the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), you can loop with iterators, loop over the length, use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Comment: See [Pretty Print C++ STL Containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite simple to accomplish using nested range-based loops (introduced by C++11):

```
for(std::set<int> const &mySet : setVector){
  for(const int i : mySet){
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/0TRNr7)

Comment: in C++ 11 you can use auto instead of "std::set<int> const &"

Comment: @Dmitriy the same things goes for "const int i"

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to my (header only) [to_string](https://github.com/DmitriyMaksimov/to_stream) library.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& s) {
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(os,","));
    return os;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& s) {
    os << "{";
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    for( ; it != s.end(); ++it)
        os << *it;

    os << "}";
    return os;
}
```

Then you can do

```
std::cout << setVector;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print them directly as :

```
for(int i=0;i<setVector.size();i++)
{
      for(set<int>::iterator iter=setVector[i].begin();iter!=setVector[i].end();iter++)
}
```